# objloader so slow with huge animation how can i accelerate it

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, blender, wavefront

My steps are:

1. I am making a model its rig animated 1000-1200 frame in blender and I will export these .obj files, therefore, I have to load 1000-1200 .obj files.
2. I am using `objloader` in c++ and I am sending `gpu` with `opengl` VBO way
3. I didn't use multithreading with `objloader`
4. All files install in 80 seconds (one file has 2000 face all triangle)

How can I accelerate it?

1. Do I have to use multithreading? Is it the only way? Then I can't use `std::string` and `std::vector` am right?
2. Can I take only rig positions from blender and can I use them over only one .obj file in OpenGL with `gltranslate` and `glrotate` to move? against load all animation model?
3. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use .obj.

Comment: what can i use suggestion ? i am beginner

Comment: FBX for example.

Comment: use any binary form 3D mesh representation. The ASCII exports are always slow. I would try binary STL.

Comment: The term you are looking for is *skinning*. With this approach, you store the model and the animation separately. Skinning is the process of applying a (skeletal) animation to a 3D model.

Comment: i heard new "skeletal animation" thank you i wanted to learn this now i need to fix how can use skeletal animation :D